# Answer to the question: "Who Wins?"

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, language, music

*Crié ala caleverti*

[miku'ilatmo

doci

pramilerfu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrNJuayBxrw)

Hint:

> The first line is in one language (actually an argot). The hyperlinked three lines are in another (plain-text, but not very legible). The final answer to the question is in yet another, and the answer takes the form "blank as blank," but it is not English.

Non-Youtube description of video contents (for accessibility/posterity purposes):

> Transcribed score of the video's song (means of visually notating the song is irrelevant to the problem):
>  [image]
>  Title text: "Blank as Blank"
>
>  Video description: Speak loudly, speak clearly, speak logically
>
>  Static image in video (relevant, but no steganography applies):
>  [image]

Comment: Your puzzle is likely to be closed as it links to external sites. It is also unclear if it is actually a puzzle or not.

Comment: @Tonks I'm voting to give the OP the benefit of the doubt, as an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle].

Comment: @Randal'Thor that's fair, I thought linking to other sites was frowned upon though? Sorry, I don't know if I've misinterpreted it as a solid rule rather than a guideline.

Comment: I assume the close votes would be "a community-specific reason" if they were about my use of a Youtube video. How is "needs details or clarity" a valid close reason for an enigmatic puzzle? You even know the form the answer will take (as an answer to the question "Who wins?"). I'll go one further and say "Blank as Blank" as the video title is also the form of the final answer.

Comment: I don't believe the transcription of the song. Each bar in the transcription is supposed to be 4/4 but has (1 crotchet rest/tie) + (1 crotchet + demisemiquaver) + (1.5 crotchets) which adds up to 3 5/8 crotchets, not 4. I haven't listened to it, but perhaps the dotted semiquaver should be a semiquaver tied to a quaver, or something like that?

Comment: I only screenshotted and posted the Musescore file used to generate the song, and they do add up correctly. The first bar is (1/4 rest) + (1/8 + 1/16 + 3/16 notes) + (3/8 note) = 1 whole note, for example. You've somehow been mistaken into getting a "(1 crotchet + demisemiquaver)" summand (perhaps you think the dot is on a 1/16?).

Comment: Just by the by for anyone intimidated by this discussion, the song demands only your ears. The score is just a visual representation of what's heard in the video.

Comment: I selected 'needs details or clarity' because as far as I could see there were no 'community specific reasons' (current options available to me are: too speculative, off topic, found elsewhere, and belongs on a different SE site) that matched with including links to outside sources. I selected needs details/clarity because I thought your question required more detail regarding what is at the links to prevent [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on with the music. In the bars on the first line (which is all I looked at carefully) the last of those grouped notes is a dotted quaver, not a dotted semiquaver, and it looked the other way to me because the beam on the middle note is way longer than I'd have expected and extends almost all the way to the stem of the third -- I didn't even notice they didn't reach all the way. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Feryll I'm not sure if I've been genuinely going crazy for this past hour or not, but is the image in the YouTube video relevant to the puzzle in any way?

Comment: @Sciborg It is. Although I will say it's one of a couple of "redundant" hints in this problem; that image in particular is like a checksum for the final answer. It's also not steganographically encoding anything.

Comment: @Feryll Fair enough. I thought I had made headway, but the amount of obscure knowledge that seems to be required is overwhelming to me and I'm throwing in the towel. Not sure how to even know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: @Sciborg Very well; thank you for showing this problem some love, at least, even if it hasn't quite loved you back. Myself or others might nonetheless like to know what your partial progress was :)

Comment: @Feryll It's too long for a comment, and partial answers are frowned upon here. I guess what frustrates me is the lack of a concrete, "correct"-feeling solve path and the combination it being both enigmatic and very complicated. If my progress up to the point where I gave up is semi-correct, the next step has to be something hidden in the music that I'm just not seeing, but after listening to it a hundred times I've got absolutely nothing and there are no clues about what to look for or whether any of the previous information applies. It feels like beating my head on a brick wall.